# Issue in WMB message broker insert to a Sybase Database Table

Tags: insert, sybase, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Currently am facing an issue while inserting data in to Sybase database 15.7 with WMB code flow. Am currently using WMB7 Broker and I have written code in our message flow which is trying to insert the data in the table directly rather than using  store procedure. The data types used in database table is 'int' and 'Image'. But insert operation is not completing anyways.

Whereas the same message flow code is inserting the data in Database table which is on Sybase 12.5.

Can this be a compatibility issue of ODBC drivers which are present in WMB7?
Any kind of direction would be great help

Answer (score 0):

It could definitely be a driver issue, in the SOE Sybase 15.7 is only listed as supported from 7.0.0.6 onwards:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1106652668319&osPlatform=AIX#sw-Databases

Are you running on this version?

Comment: Yes am Using Sybase 15.7.

Comment: Is there any thing with Data buffer issue.?

Comment: My question was aimed more at the Broker versions as different fixpacks ship different updates of the DataDirect drivers. Are you running 7.0.0.6?

Comment: I am using Broker Version 7006.

Comment: What symptoms do you see..do you get an exception and the flow rolls back, does the call hang or does the call appear to complete but the data is not present in the db?

Comment: Thanks Dave for your help, It has been resolved now. Actually it was image datatype which was giving problems while communication from WMB to Sybase. I Have changed the Data type 'varbinary' in DB and it has started working in order

Comment: my solution does not seem to work for large chunk of data. I have created one store proc to insert the data for image datatype but its has give me the error.22003 / 0 / [IBM][ODBC Sybase Wire Protocol driver]A SQL_C_BINARY parameter was passed an incorrect number of bytes.

Comment: Where as for a POC when I tried to insert the data from C++ code it was working fine. So I can sense this certainly IBM/ODBC compatibility issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually for resolving this issue we have changed the datatype from Image to varbinary in Database Table. And all started working in order

Comment: The following page lists the data type mapping: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ak05730_.htm so IMAGE should certainly be usable.